# Spring + Angular / IE gets 403 on PUT (others don't)

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, put, http-status-code-403

I have a spring webapp with spring security(3.2.3, so no CSRF protection) and angular.

In a controller i have a method like this one to update the users pw:

```
@RequestMapping("/accountinfo/password", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.PUT))
@ResponseBody
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
open fun updateOwnPassword(user: User, @RequestBody password: String) {
    val editedUser = user
    editedUser.password = encoder.encode(password)
    userRepository.save(editedUser)
}
```

The request is done via angular Service:

```
 function changeOwnPassword(newPassword) {
        return $http
            .put('accountinfo/password', newPassword)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data
            });
    }
```

This works fine in every browser i tested with. Except if using IE 11.0.35 in a Citrix environment (Works outside of it,but can't see any specific configuration).
In that case i get 403 on the Request. When i change the method to POST it works fine again. I could do that for every function where i got this problem of course, but that doesn't seem like a clean solution.

As far as my research goes, i think it's something wrong with the way the browser writes the Request, but that's were i can't find out what to do.

EDIT:
I compared the request headers of both IE 11.0.35 inside and outside of Citrix and they seem exactly the same. The only difference is that the working version uses DNT=1 and the non-working version as WOW64 in the User-Agent attributes?

UPDATE:
I found out that it happens with DELETE too

Comment: Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172915/jquery-ajax-put-request-issue-in-internet-explorer

Comment: I am already using  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">. Also please note that it works with the Internet Explorer outside of Citrix

Comment: Tried that solution anyway and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: The client sends the Requests through an additional Proxy that doesn't like PUT and DELETE and just cuts the session cookies off of it. We are adressing that problem with putting the tokens in the header in the future.